# To enable and disable the android notification

Tags: android, notifications

i want to create a notification app which has switch (enable and disable) buttons.when i click the enable button the notification is came and when i click disable button the notification cannot come to the app or stop.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TQA3.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id";
Button sendBtn;
Switch switchBtn,switchbtn2;
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
SharedPreferences prefs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendBtn= findViewById(R.id.send_token);
    prefEditor= 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit();

prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    switchbtn2= findViewById(R.id.switch3);
switchbtn2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, 
boolean b) {
                Switch a = switchbtn2;
                if(a.isClickable()) {


                    if (switchbtn2.isChecked()) {
                        shownotifi();
                        prefEditor.putString("checked", "yes");
                        prefEditor.apply();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //To Stop notification?????
                    prefEditor.putString("checked","no");
                    prefEditor.apply();
                }
            }

            public void shownotifi() {
                 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                builder.setContentTitle("This is heading");
              builder.setContentText("This is description");

builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                Notification notification = builder.build();
                NotificationManager notificationManager= . 
 (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: `.notify(0,builder.build());` I think it's bad to use `0` as notification ID. Not sure actually about this. So you have the notification ID, by which you can cancel notification.

Comment: ok forgot the above code.i want enable and disable notification using switch buttons.can you give any idea.

Comment: as I said, use the notification ID that you have used, to cancel notification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your switch is on then call .notify(id,builder.build()) else remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

Common code in MyFirebaseMessagingService class

val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND or Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setGroupSummary(true)

```
    val notificationManager =
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val notificationChannel =
            NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, importance)
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
        notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
        notificationBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

    }
```

When Switch is on

```
notificationManager.notify(
        (System.currentTimeMillis() and 0xfffffff).toInt(),
        notificationBuilder.build()
    )
```

When Switch is off removed or comment above code.